# thread_fork working on kernel

Tags: c, pthreads, os161

I am working on OS161 where C pthread library is not primarily supported. My current objective is to understand the sys calls and make some simple programs run.

my simple function has following code:

`int id = 1;`

`long id2 = 1;`

`int ret = thread_fork("myThread", (void *)id, id2, void (*function)((void *)id, id2), NULL);`

```
    kprintf("\nHello World\n");
    return;
```

`

where call to thread_fork is `int thread_fork(const char *name,
                void *data1, unsigned long data2,
                void (*func)(void *, unsigned long),
                struct thread **ret);`

I ahve changed conf.kern file to include this file while booting and have changed main.c to add this function call. Everything works fine if I remove thread call.

is it not the proper way to implement thread code or
Am I going wrong anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with OS161, but you've got the syntax for passing a function pointer in C wrong, and you've not given `thread_fork` anywhere to return the thread pointer.

First, the function pointer. `thread_fork` expects a pointer to a function that takes two parameters. Your function should look like this:

```
void function(void *data1, unsigned long data2) {
    kprintf("Called with data1=%p, data2=%ld\n", data1, data2);
}
```

Then your call to `thread_fork` looks like this. Note there's storage for the returned thread pointer, which may be necessary if OS161 doesn't handle the NULL case:

```
int id1 = 1;
unsigned long id2 = 2;
struct thread *thr;

thread_fork("myThread", &id1, id2, function, &thr);
```

Here's a [worked example on function pointers](http://denniskubes.com/2013/03/22/basics-of-function-pointers-in-c/).

Comment: Thanks a lot....
now the output is : warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: You'll have to show the precise code, and the precise error message including line number. That fragment compiles without warnings on gcc here.